# LINQ determine if children of children exists

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq

Currently I have a database design as such:

`Movie` 1..1-->0..* `MovieRelease` 1..1-->0..* `Performance`

I would like to write a LINQ statement to select all `Movie` that have one or more `performance`. This is what I came up with but it isn't working.

```
var instances = await GeneralModelRepository.GetQueryable<Movie>()
    .Include(x => x.MovieReleases)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Performances)
    .Where(x => x.MovieReleases.Any())
    .Where(x => x.MovieReleases.All(x => x.Performances.Any()))
    .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var instances = await GeneralModelRepository.GetQueryable<Movie>()
    .Include(x => x.MovieReleases)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Performances)
    .Where(x => x.MovieReleases.SelectMany(r => r.Performances).Any())
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```